# ngDirective is not watching

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to make angular works with semantic ui, specifically dropdown searching box. I have tried multiple things and I found that because the input type is set to be hidden, ng-model is not going to work. And because the change to the element is not directly triggered by the user, the ng-change also won't work.

My idea is to use a directive and try to monitor the input element's attribute, because after selecting something, the value attribute changes. I think ngDirective should be able to implement the ng-model and ng-change by using scope.$watch

I tried this but the scope value has not been changed.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'my.controllers'
]);

var controllers = angular.module('my.controllers', []);
controllers.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;
});

app.directive("ngSearch", function(){
    function link($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log($scope.value);
        $scope.$watch("value", function(newValue, oldValue){
            console.log(newValue, oldValue);
            console.log("value updated");
            ctrl.$setViewValue($scope.value);
        }, true);

        setTimeout(function() {console.log(attrs.value);}, 6000);
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            "value": "@",
        },
        link: link,
    }
})

$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-conroller="MyController">
    <div class="ui fluid multiple search normal selection dropdown">
      <input type="hidden" name="country" value="test1" ng-search ng-model="users">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <div class="default text">Select testing</div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="test1">test1</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="test2">test2</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="test3">test3</div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

same version in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e5aes1fe/1/